# Unable to edit the trust using gpg and a command file

Tags: gnupg

I am trying to write a plugin to my build tool which wraps GnuPG.

I have managed to do everything so far but the one thing I am stuck on is how to trust a newly added key without affecting the trust of existing keys.

If I first list the keys:

```
root@7353afd2c546:/# gpg --with-keygrip --with-secret --batch --with-colons --status-fd 1 --list-keys
tru::1:1542186184:0:3:1:5
pub:-:4096:1:B6A8B64B909CAF2F:1541574504:::-:::scESC:::#:::23::0:
fpr:::::::::DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F:
grp:::::::::9BEB53AD0C68FC629997DB0597DDD758C632B9CD:
uid:-::::1541574504::5D90CFACEB3B07D9914327FD2981787B56ACD4A2::Testy <test@example.com>::::::::::0:
sub:-:4096:1:0E839DDD93691327:1541574504::::::e:::+:::23:
fpr:::::::::B9A633DBD1A309DB71ED55940E839DDD93691327:
grp:::::::::6D475E5BA6A1502B1C083F780A537DBC15643EEA:
```

We see that there is no value for the validity.

Now I have a command file:

```
root@7353afd2c546:/# cat /root/.gnupg/commands
trust
5
save
```

And when I run:

```
root@7353afd2c546:/# gpg --batch --yes --status-fd 1 --command-file /root/.gnupg/commands --edit-key DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F 0
Secret subkeys are available.


pub:-:4096:1:B6A8B64B909CAF2F:1541574504:0::-:::sc
fpr:::::::::DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F:
ssb:-:4096:1:0E839DDD93691327:1541574504:0:::::e
fpr:::::::::B9A633DBD1A309DB71ED55940E839DDD93691327:
uid:-::::::::Testy <test@example.com>:::S9 S8 S7 S2 H10 H9 H8 H11 H2 Z2 Z3 Z1,mdc,no-ks-modify:1,p::
[GNUPG:] GET_LINE keyedit.prompt
[GNUPG:] GOT_IT

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

pub:-:4096:1:B6A8B64B909CAF2F:1541574504:0::-:::sc
fpr:::::::::DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F:
ssb:-:4096:1:0E839DDD93691327:1541574504:0:::::e
fpr:::::::::B9A633DBD1A309DB71ED55940E839DDD93691327:
uid:-::::::::Testy <test@example.com>:::S9 S8 S7 S2 H10 H9 H8 H11 H2 Z2 Z3 Z1,mdc,no-ks-modify:1,p::
[GNUPG:] GET_LINE edit_ownertrust.value
[GNUPG:] GOT_IT
[GNUPG:] GET_LINE edit_ownertrust.value
[GNUPG:] GOT_IT

[GNUPG:] GET_LINE keyedit.prompt
[GNUPG:] GOT_IT
```

We see here that looks as though it successfully read the input from the file. However when I list the keys again the validity has not changed.

Yet if I edit the key manually:

```
root@7353afd2c546:/# gpg --edit-key DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4; Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret subkeys are available.

pub  rsa4096/B6A8B64B909CAF2F
     created: 2018-11-07  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: never         validity: unknown
ssb  rsa4096/0E839DDD93691327
     created: 2018-11-07  expires: never       usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Testy <test@example.com>

gpg> trust
pub  rsa4096/B6A8B64B909CAF2F
     created: 2018-11-07  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: never         validity: unknown
ssb  rsa4096/0E839DDD93691327
     created: 2018-11-07  expires: never       usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Testy <test@example.com>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 5
Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y

pub  rsa4096/B6A8B64B909CAF2F
     created: 2018-11-07  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: unknown
ssb  rsa4096/0E839DDD93691327
     created: 2018-11-07  expires: never       usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Testy <test@example.com>
Please note that the shown key validity is not necessarily correct
unless you restart the program.

gpg> save
Key not changed so no update needed.
```

Then it works:

```
root@7353afd2c546:/# gpg --with-keygrip --with-secret --batch --with-colons --status-fd 1 --list-keys
gpg: checking the trustdb
tru:o:1:1542190815:1:3:1:5
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F 0
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
pub:u:4096:1:B6A8B64B909CAF2F:1541574504:::u:::scESC:::#:::23::0:
fpr:::::::::DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F:
grp:::::::::9BEB53AD0C68FC629997DB0597DDD758C632B9CD:
uid:u::::1541574504::5D90CFACEB3B07D9914327FD2981787B56ACD4A2::Testy <test@example.com>::::::::::0:
sub:u:4096:1:0E839DDD93691327:1541574504::::::e:::+:::23:
fpr:::::::::B9A633DBD1A309DB71ED55940E839DDD93691327:
grp:::::::::6D475E5BA6A1502B1C083F780A537DBC15643EEA:
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

Your command file has `trust 5` in a single line, even though the `trust` command does not accept parameters. Instead it shows a separate prompt for the menu selection, which means the response should be in a separate line as well. **Each prompt needs its own line in the command-file.**

So the trust is not updated because GnuPG receives the word `save` when it needs a number.

A faster way to set ownertrust is:

```
echo "DE29CBE0AC9B2EB810E694D7B6A8B64B909CAF2F:6:" | gpg --import-ownertrust
```

(The `6` is not a typo – it is the internal trust value, not the menu item number.)

Comment: Having them on separate lines makes no difference. I tried them on separate lines first.

Doesn't `--import-ownertrust` overwrite the existing trust database? I only want to modify the trust for a single key and not touch the trust for the others.

Comment: I have updated the example with the parameters on separate lines.